# Mysql get both highscores and all submitted scores

Tags: mysql

I have the following highscores table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `highscores` (
  `lid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `dateadded` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`lid`,`username`),
  KEY `score` (`lid`,`score`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and have the following queries:

1- list users with most highscores

```
SELECT
   h.userid,h.username ,count(h.username)
FROM
    highscores h inner join
    (select lid, min(score) as minscore,COUNT( * ) AS totalScores
     FROM highscores GROUP BY lid) t on h.lid = t.lid and h.score = t.minscore
GROUP BY h.username ORDER BY `count(h.username)`  DESC
```

2- list  users with most submitted scores

```
SELECT username, COUNT( * ) 
FROM highscores
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
```

What I would like is one query that gets both a users total highscores and submitted scores, sorted by users with the most highscores.

something like(not sure how to format a table)-

-Username--highscores--submittedscores

-John---------65--------------755

-Jill------------42--------------1435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select h.username, h.highScores, s.submittedScores
from
(
    SELECT
        h.username, count(h.username) as highScores
    FROM
        highscores h inner join
        (select lid, min(score) as minscore,COUNT( * ) AS totalScores
         FROM highscores GROUP BY lid) t on h.lid = t.lid and h.score = t.minscore
    GROUP BY h.username
) as h
inner join
(
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) as submittedScores
    FROM highscores
    GROUP BY username
) as s
    on s.username = h.username
order by h.highScores desc, s.submittedScores
```

I just took your two results and combined them with an inner join. Isn't that what you need?

I haven't poured over your two queries so it may well be that a simpler version is possible.

Comment: Awesome, yeah thats exactly what I needed to do. I was having a hell of a time trying to do so. Thank you very much